# Haskell - Iterate Tuple with Different Functions

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to to iterate the cand data in order to apply a function "pt_string".

```
Pt :: (Float, Float)
Person :: (Pt, Pt, [Pt], Float)
```

My idea is to call that function "pt_string" in a different way for each element of the tupple.

For example:

1. pt_string `Point` (first)
2. map pt_string `[Point]`
3. pt_string `Point` (second)
4. show "Tmp"

So far, I got:

```
pt_string :: pt -> String
pt_string pt =  "(" ++ show (fst pt) ++ "," ++ show (snd pt) ++ ")\n"
```

Which works fine. But how can I create **cand_to_string :: cand -> String** in the above order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
type Candidate = (Point, Point, [Point], Float)
```

you can use

```
candidate_to_string :: Candidate -> String
candidate_to_string (p1, p2, ps, f) =
   "(" ++
   point_to_string p1 ++ ", " ++
   point_to_string p2 ++ ", " ++
   points_to_string ps ++ ", " ++
   show f ++
   ")"
```

which relies on

```
points_to_string :: [Point] -> String
points_to_string ps = "[" ++ intercalate ", " (map point_to_string ps) ++ "]"
```

exploiting `Data.List.intercalate` to add commas between the points.

Also note that, if you simply want the standard list/tuple printing format, you can directly use

```
candidate_to_string :: Candidate -> String
candidate_to_string = show
```